# Problems posting from mobile

Tags: bug

OK. I think the mobile version of the site (or at least of some SE sites), and the Android app, both need an update. Let me give some timeline.

The first item is [this meta Math SE question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20970/why-cant-i-post-from-my-mobile). Here is the history:

1. I have a question to post.
2. I write it down and try posting it from the `Internet` browser on my Android mobile.
3. I get redirected to a page saying:

> Page Not Found
>
> We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.
>
> Try searching for similar questions Browse recent questions Browse popular tags
>
> If you feel something is missing that should be here, contact us.
>
> Just like the page for a deleted question to a user who can't see it.

4. I try again, same result.
5. I try from the app, and I get an error message.
6. I therefore post on Meta Math SE asking «what is going on here??», which is the link above.
7. I try posting that body with a garbage title and a casual tag on the main site, and I get the message «The question is not available, it might have been deleted̀».
8. Notifications from comments make me notice that the question on main was posted from the app and the garbage post was *also* posted.
9. A query tells me the attempts from the browser seem to have actually failed.

I let the issue rot a bit because no-one answered my meta Math SE question and I had other worries up my sleeve.

*But* then I find myself posting from my mobile again, this time on Chinese SE, and the results, if I remember correctly, are the same. I definitely remember a successful post from the app with the error message, and having to look for the question some way.

So what is this posting problem??

Also, why can't one copy the URL from a question on "homepage" of the app? That made finding the URL to the Chinese SE question considerably more of a nuisance since I had to refresh the browser a couple of times...